# How to read a .csv file in Python/Pandas in which comma(,) is a delimiter and present in the column name as well?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file like below, in which comma is present in some of the column name as well.

```
#NAME,DATE,RECORDS,QUANTITY
Johb.W. Smith, LLC,03/01/2018 to 03/29/2018,728,32309.77
XXX Industrial Ltd, Inc.,07/27/2017 to 07/28/2017,2,312.00
XYSC,03/02/2018 to 03/29/2018,387,4468.50
```

When I try reading that in Python/Panda, the column in which there is a comma, is available are shifting(as the system is treating that as new row value, which is actually not).

```
#NAME                         DATE                       RECORDS
Johb.W. Smith                 LLC                        03/01/2018         728.0   
XXX Industrial Ltd            Inc.                       07/27/2017      2.0    
XYSC                          03/02/2018                 387
```

For.Ex- In ROW no-1 , Johb.W. Smith LLC is a complete name (which was actually seperated by comma in the original csv file, hence in panda treating as a new cell value)

Can anyone suggest how to get rid of this? The actual output should look like this:

```
#NAME                      DATE                      RECORDS                 
Johb.W. Smith LLC          03/01/2018 to 03/29/2018  728    
XXX Industrial Ltd Inc.    07/27/2017 to 07/28/2017  2  
XYSC                       03/02/2018 to 03/29/2018  387
```

Comment: Did you create the CSV in the first place? It's possible to have commas in a single column so I suspect the issue arises in how the CSV is created. If so, it's easier to fix the issue there if you can.

Comment: I can not touch the .csv file. That is how the requirement is..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem in `csv`, because if separator is `,` and some values contain `,` obviously are added quoting to values for valid csv:

Not general solution below is if problematic values are only in first or last columns.

Create one column `DataFrame` by separator which is not in data like `|` and split by [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) (`split`) with parameter `n` by `number of columns - 1`, here by `3`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""#NAME,DATE,RECORDS,QUANTITY
Johb.W. Smith, LLC,03/01/2018 to 03/29/2018,728,32309.77
XXX Industrial Ltd, Inc.,07/27/2017 to 07/28/2017,2,312.00
XYSC,03/02/2018 to 03/29/2018,387,4468.50"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="|")

df1 = df.iloc[:, 0].str.rsplit(',', n=3, expand=True)
df1.columns = df.columns.str.split(',')[0]
print (df1)
                      #NAME                      DATE RECORDS  QUANTITY
0        Johb.W. Smith, LLC  03/01/2018 to 03/29/2018     728  32309.77
1  XXX Industrial Ltd, Inc.  07/27/2017 to 07/28/2017       2    312.00
2                      XYSC  03/02/2018 to 03/29/2018     387   4468.50
```

Comment: rsplit(n=3) relies on the last three columns not containging spurious commas,  which works for this data set.

Comment: @Jasen - Exactly, I try explain it in answer.

Comment: The code is working fine perfectly, I hope comma will be placed in the first column only. Thank you !

Comment: Can you please this part a little more- "split by rsplit (split) with parameter n by number of columns - 1, here by 3:" How the spliting is happening ?

Comment: `rsplit` means it split first n separators from right side, so in your sample after split by `3 of ,` splitting is stopped and 4 columns are created

Answer (score 0):

Enter the data, or edit the file to correct it, by hand.

Heroic attempts could be made using regex or other patterm matching to guess where the values should be separated, but these will not work in all cases, and are likely to fail unpredicatbly.

If someone promised you a csv file, reject this one and ask them nicely to provuide a correctly formatted CSV file.